# ServiceStack always Default Redirect to /metadata even when Default.cshtml present

Tags: servicestack, appharbor

I have a ServiceStack project with ServiceStack Razor added.  Any time I try and navigate to the root of the site, I'm getting redirected to /metadata.

This does not happen on my dev machine, only in my hosted environment (AppHarbor).

I do have a Default.cshtml in the root of my project.

Navigating to other URLs work fine: `/default1.cshtml`, `/myservicewithviews`

I've tried messing with the `DefaultRedirectPath` in my AppHost, but that didn't help.

Trying to force it `DefaultRedirectPath = "default.cshtml"` result in a redirect loop.  Which makes sense.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppHarbor only publishes files marked "Content" when building projects [(AppHb FAQ)](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions).  This file was the only one not marked content and why I was only experiencing this in my hosted environment and could access all other content.

Not detecting a default document causes ServiceStack to set a RedirectHttpHandler to /metadata - [shown around here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.cs#L71)

Another noteworthy point is that AppHarbor's load-balancer causes their internal port numbers to show up in ServiceStack URLs when performing things like Response Redirects.

To fix this problem, you add the following to your Web.Config:

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- AppHarbor Setting to stop AppHb load balancer internal port numbers from showing up in URLs-->
    <add key="aspnet:UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

You could also configure this setting in your AppHarbor config panel.